# jquery remove all first span elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
<h2><span>1</span><span>2</span></h2>
<h2><span>1</span><span>2</span></h2>
<h2><span>1</span><span>2</span></h2>
<h2><span>1</span><span>2</span></h2>
```

I would like to remove the first span element **from all the h2 elements**.

I tried the following which only remove the first span from the first h2:

```
$("h2 span:first").remove();
$("h2 span").first().remove();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector:

```
$("h2 span:first-child").remove();
```

Comment: +1: that did it thanks! I need to wait 12 minutes to give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("h2").each(function(){
   $(this).find("span:first").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwmN6/) as an example):

```
jQuery('h2 span:first-child').remove();
```